# PHP captcha Image

Tags: php, cookies, captcha

I am using a captcha image verifier in my PHP form. The form uses a cookie to check the verfication code entered by the user. Is there anyother way to do this other than using a cookie?

Comment: Yes. Any other questions?

Answer (score 4):

Cookies are a very bad idea in this case. Instead, you should use a variable set in the [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) PHP superglobal. At the top of your captcha-input page, add this (minimal version):

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['captchaCode'] = /* whatever */
```

`session_start()` documentation can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php).

Then, when the form is submitted, check that the value submitted from the form is the same as the one in `$_SESSION['captchaCode']`:

```
session_start();

if($_SESSION['captchaCode'] == $_POST['captchaCode'])
{
    // Do interesting things
}
```

Do bear in mind that this is a very simple, generic way of doing it. If you're using reCAPTCHA or Securimg then they will have their own ways of validating the captchas they generate.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use cookies, you can just see if what they enter matches directly with what you have in the database of captcha entries; that is if you have a database of possible captchas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script that is very easy to use and setup. This script just creates the image but it is not tough to incorporate the verification. You can download the script [here](http://test.nlmg.us/captcha/) to verify the captach image use either php or javascript to make sure the post value is equal to $_SESSION['security_number'] and your done.